# How to deal with medium-sized binary files in GIT?

Tags: git, version-control, blob, storage, git-lfs

All our team uses Windows machines.

I have a certain number of medium-sized binary files used by my program. In total about 100 megabytes. These files seldom change, therefore I don't want every commit to include all of them.

Initially I wanted to use git-lfs and replace all of them by pointers, but it turns out that git-lfs doesn't support the file:// protocol, and I am not allowed to install anything on the machine, so I cannot install the git-lfs-server.

Any suggestions on how to avoid the exploding repository problem in this case?

Comment: The files are only included in a commit if they change. Otherwise the existing files will simply be referenced by the new commit.

Comment: Since you can not install any software to manage the binary files in the repo, is it ok for your team to manage the binary files in a separate repo?

Comment: Don't track them in the Git repository. Store them in an FTP server or an SVN repository. Maintain a configuration file and a script to fetch these binaries of the right version when needed.